# Dynamic Cell Refernce

Tags: microsoft-excel

=IF(L3 = "Rent", 450 - K3, 450)

I have this if statement doing what I want, however, I am hoping there is a way to check the entire "L" Row for the word "Rent" and subtract the adjacent "K" cell from 450... is there a way to do this dynamic check in excel?

Answer (score 3):

Is there only one match at most? Perhaps try SUMIF

`=450-SUMIF(L:L,"Rent",K:K)`

Comment: @MichaelChoi Please accept the answer by ticking it and mark thread as solved)